# I cannot get the meaning of "check s-box"

Tags: differential-analysis

In second lecture of cryptography, we had a lecture "Block cyphers" and teacher gave me  permuted array of numbers 1...10 and letters "a"..."f" and asked me to find XOR profile. But I do not have any idea what I need to do and do not get what XOR table,s-box is. Could you give me a fundamentals(basics) to understand, what we are doing, I could not get information from google.

Comment: See table 7 of this great tutorial http://www.cs.bc.edu/~straubin/crypto2017/heys.pdf, Once you understand I'll hint you another page.

Comment: Ready for the next help?